# Why is there an occupied space in the window after clearing the current figure?

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm building a GUI application to plot rows of data. The current issue with the code is that there is still an occupied space in the window despite clearing the current figure with plt.clf().

Is there something else that I should be aware of when working with FigureCanvasTkAgg or matplotlib.pyplot?

I have tried plt.cla(), plt.clf() as well as plt.close(). Both plt.cla() and plt.clf() appear to clear out the data while plt.close() closes out of the application which is not desired.

```
class PlotPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.canvas = None
        self.xlist, self.ylist = [1,2,3,4], [1,4,9,16]
        label = tk.Label(self, text="PlotPage")
        label.pack(pady=5)
        self.f = None

        buttonPlot = tk.Button(self, text="Show Plot", command=self.plot)
        buttonPlot.pack(pady=5)

        buttonClear = tk.Button(self, text="Clear Plot Field", command = self.clearPlotPage)
        buttonClear.pack(pady=5)

    def plot(self):
        if self.canvas == None:
            if self.f == None:
                self.f = plt.figure(1,figsize=(8,4), dpi=100)   
            plt.plot(self.xlist,self.ylist, 'ro')

            self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f, self)
            self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
            self.canvas.draw()

            toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.canvas, self)
            toolbar.update()
            self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

            print("Stuff has been plotted")
        else:
            print("Plot already plotted please clear first")\

    def clearPlotPage(self):
#         self.f == None
#         plt.clf()
        plt.cla()
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas = None
        print("Plot Page has been cleared")
```

I am looking to be able to plot the data on the tkinter window and then clear the axes for new data to be plotted on the same figure; however, what actually happens is that after the figure/axes are cleared, the data is plotted on a new figure/axes rather than on the cleared figure/axes.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `canvas.get_tk_widget().destroy()`.

```
class PlotPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ...

    def plot(self):
        if self.canvas == None:
            if self.f == None:
                self.f = plt.figure(1,figsize=(8,4), dpi=100)
            plt.plot(self.xlist,self.ylist, 'ro')
            self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f, self)
            self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
            toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.canvas, self)
            toolbar.update()
            print("Stuff has been plotted")
        else:
            print("Plot already plotted please clear first")

    def clearPlotPage(self):
        plt.cla()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().destroy()
        self.canvas = None
        print("Plot Page has been cleared")
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to [Henry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55469296/1356000), I would suggest you should not create a new figure everytime. Instead, you should keep your figure and canvas (and axes probably), and only update the *content* of the plot. Like so (this code is untested for the moment):

```
class PlotPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.f = plt.figure(1, figsize=(8, 4), dpi=100)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f, self)
        self.ax = self.f.add_subplot(111)
        self.isPlotted = False

        self.xlist, self.ylist = [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 9, 16]
        label = tk.Label(self, text="PlotPage")
        label.pack(pady=5)

        buttonPlot = tk.Button(self, text="Show Plot", command=self.plot)
        buttonPlot.pack(pady=5)

        buttonClear = tk.Button(self, text="Clear Plot Field", command=self.clearPlotPage)
        buttonClear.pack(pady=5)

    def plot(self):
        if not self.isPlotted:
            self.ax.plot(self.xlist, self.ylist, 'ro')

            self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
            self.canvas.draw()

            toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.canvas, self)
            toolbar.update()
            self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

            print("Stuff has been plotted")
        else:
            print("Plot already plotted please clear first")

    def clearPlotPage(self):
        self.ax.clear()
        self.canvas.draw()
        print("Plot Page has been cleared")
```